# Error handling in WPF PasswordBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, passwordbox, custom-error-handling

I have always admired the way Josh Smith has built his [sample application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).
And I have also tried to emulate the way in which the ViewModels of his application implements the IDataErrorInfo property and through a custom DataTemplate renders the errors before the user.
Here is the data template that he uses to show the error:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ValidationError}">
  <TextBlock FontSize="10"
             FontStyle="Italic"
             Foreground="Red"
             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
             Margin="0,1"
             Text="{Binding Path=ErrorContent}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

A working sample of this data template getting consumed is as follows:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtUsername"
         Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         Width="300"
         Margin="2" 
         Text="{Binding Path=Username,
             ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"/>

<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                  Content="{Binding ElementName=txtUsername,
                      Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem}"/>
```

The default ErrorTemplate of the textbox (a red boundary that appears around it) is replaced by a new error template in which a content presenter placed just below the text box will convey the error to the user — certainly a superior and more elegant template.

If you have read the above code, you might well have guessed that I am trying to create a login form.

Unfortunately, login forms demand password (and subsequently PasswordBox). PasswordBox does not provide "Password" as dependency property. I did not want to break the MVVM guideline of trying to avoid code behind as much as possible and so was tempted to go for the [PasswordBoxAssistant](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html) class mentioned [here](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html).
This otherwise is a nice solution, save one thing. It is not letting me validate the Password Box with Josh's data template.
I have validated the password property of my ViewModel for not being empty. The property is getting validated as my "Login" button is not getting enabled without the user filling in password. But the "Enter password" message that I did set as a part of this property validation is not being rendered by the Content presenter that lies below the PasswordBox. Here goes the code:

```
<Label Content="Password:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2" />

<PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordBox"
             Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             Margin="2"
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" 
             ff:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="true"  
             ff:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password,
                 Mode=TwoWay,
                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Content="{Binding ElementName=PasswordBox,
                  Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem}"/>
```

Needless to say that the ff in the above code stands for the namespace reference:

```
xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:MyProject.UserViews"
```

I am sure, this problem is happening because the Password property has got extended by the helper class. If I drop this approach, I will have to remove the Password property from the IDataErrorInfo Implementation and on Login button click will have to verify it, presenting the user with a message box. But not without compromising consistency. I am not much aware of Dependency Properties; can there be any workaround? Will altering the helper class in some way let me have the red error message back in place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` in your Password binding, so perhaps that is your  problem. By default, that is set to `False` which means the binding won't alert the UI of any validation errors.

---

That said, I think the `Password` is intentionally not a `DependencyProperty` because you really shouldn't be storing passwords as plain text.

Usually I end up passing the `PasswordBox.Password` (or the entire `PasswordBox`) as a `CommandParameter` to my `LoginCommand`, then it can take the data and do whatever it wants to it. Usually this means hashing it or something and comparing it with the stored password's hash to see if its the same. If the login fails, I write the associated error message to a property in my ViewModel, which is bound to the login UI.

```
<Button Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyPasswordBox, Path=Password}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had this option before I jumped into this design. In my case, a login module is more of a formal design to conserve the traditional approach. My problem is not the design I can device yet another way to pass the password to the ViewModel. My problem is How is the  PasswordBoxAssistant blocking the password from getting validated.

Comment: @James Did you set `ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"` in your password binding?

Comment: "That said, I don't see ValidatesOnDataErrors=True in your Password binding, so perhaps that is your problem."
@Rachel there was the catch. Thanks for pointing that out. I am embarrassed at throwing my homework to you.

Comment: @James Glad it worked out :) I re-arranged my answer so that line is at the top

Comment: Can we stop this "not storing password in memory" business? The password property of the box __is a string in the first place__. So this is just cargo cult, as the darned string is already in memory, easily readable with e.g. snoop!

Comment: @flq That is true, however I was thinking the `PasswordBox.Password` is typed in by the user and only exists as part of the application for the lifetime of the `PasswordBox` object, while something like `User.Password` exists for the lifetime of the `User` object and would stay around in memory much longer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but you're not turning off the default ErrorTemplate for the  `PasswordBox`. (ie no `Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}`)

EDIT: Can you use something like [Wpf Inspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/) to check the content of `Validation.Errors` of the `PasswordBox` to ensure that the error is actually there (or even just bind an ItemsControl to it) ?

Comment: thanks for marking that but that can't be the problem. Because not turning off the default error template would have made the default error template to appear. But nothing is appearing.