# PasswordBox validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

The Password property of the `PasswordBox` element is not a `DependencyObject` so cannot be bound (there is no Text property).  Capturing the password as the user types is possible by attaching a message to the `PasswordChanged` event, passing the source and grabbing it in the view model.  However the lack of binding means there no opportunity to set `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` so the `IDataErrorInfo` methods are never call meaning any error template is never activated.  Anyone know how to resolve this? That is, is there another way to have an element invoke a call to the view model for the `IDataErrorInfo` indexer?

One legitimate question might be why would you want to validate a password.

Two reasons:

1) To let the user know the password is required.

2) to let the user know if the password and password confirmation are the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942259/error-handling-in-wpf-passwordbox?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Here is also a good aswer: http://wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html 
However, if you do so the password would be stored as a plain text in the memory.

Maybe then it is better to change the attached property "Password" from the example to something like "IsEmpty" and "PasswordHash".

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer by Alex below, I too used the information in this article;

http://wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html

Where I did the following which allows validation;

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBox x:Name="plain1" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordHelperBox" w:PasswordHelper.Attach="True" w:PasswordHelper.Password="{Binding Text, ElementName=plain1, Mode=TwoWay}" TabIndex="2" Margin="0,2,30,2"/>
</Grid>
```

Where "Password" is the property to bind to.

**Helper Class;**

```cs
public static class PasswordHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Password",
        typeof(string), typeof(PasswordHelper),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnPasswordPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Attach",
        typeof(bool), typeof(PasswordHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, Attach));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty IsUpdatingProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsUpdating", typeof(bool), 
       typeof(PasswordHelper));


    public static void SetAttach(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(AttachProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetAttach(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (bool)dp.GetValue(AttachProperty);
    }

    public static string GetPassword(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (string)dp.GetValue(PasswordProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPassword(DependencyObject dp, string value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(PasswordProperty, value);
    }

    private static bool GetIsUpdating(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (bool)dp.GetValue(IsUpdatingProperty);
    }

    private static void SetIsUpdating(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(IsUpdatingProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnPasswordPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordBox passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;
        passwordBox.PasswordChanged -= PasswordChanged;

        if (!(bool)GetIsUpdating(passwordBox))
        {
            passwordBox.Password = (string)e.NewValue;
        }
        passwordBox.PasswordChanged += PasswordChanged;
    }

    private static void Attach(DependencyObject sender,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordBox passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;

        if (passwordBox == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.OldValue)
        {
            passwordBox.PasswordChanged -= PasswordChanged;
        }

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            passwordBox.PasswordChanged += PasswordChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordBox passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;
        SetIsUpdating(passwordBox, true);
        SetPassword(passwordBox, passwordBox.Password);
        SetIsUpdating(passwordBox, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying there simply is no solution for validating a password box and putting a red border around a password box after validating? I'm not sure why people have settled for a password box hack. This solution certainly is not allowed in my shop.

Comment: To see why this is a bad idea, read the following article: http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/security-risk-in-binding-wpf-passwordbox-password/ It is indirectly referenced through the tutorial provided by PGallagher, but it can't be stressed enough.